# Sql Server default value average of x rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, average, database-migration

I have the following trigger running on MySQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW SET
new.AVG_COLUMN1 = (SELECT avg(COLUMN1) FROM (SELECT COLUMN1 from table ORDER BY DateTimeCol DESC LIMIT 20) as COLUMN1_A), 
new.AVG_COLUMN2 = (SELECT avg(COLUMN2) FROM (SELECT COLUMN2 from table ORDER BY DateTimeCol DESC LIMIT 20) as COLUMN2_A), 
new.AVG_COLUMN3 = (SELECT avg(COLUMN3) FROM (SELECT COLUMN3 from table ORDER BY DateTimeCol DESC LIMIT 20) as COLUMN3_A)
```

Basically my goal here is to set a automatic, default value in the AVG_COLUMNx column, based on the last 20 entries in COLUMNx, whenever a new row is inserted. This is working fine in MySQL using the mentioned trigger.

I am in the process of migrating my project to Sql Server Express from MS, and I'm trying to do the same there. Does anyone have any good pointers as to how I could accomplish this? Using triggers, computed columns, etc?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Like I was saying, the trigger I have working is on MySQL, but I am looking for an SQL Server equivalent (I am planning to migrate my project from MySQL to SQL Server Express).

Comment: Yes, I noticed after reading a bit more closely.  I've added the `MySQL` and `database-migration` tags to the post to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic would be different in SQL Server because it would be using `inserted` rather than `new`.  Basically:

```
update t
    set AVG_ROW1 = tt.avg1, 
        AVG_ROW2 = tt.avg2, 
        AVG_ROW3 = tt.avg3
    from table t join
         inserted i
         on i.pk = t.pk outer apply
         (select avg(Row1) as avg1, avg(Row2) as avg2, avg(Row3) as avg3
          from (select top 20 t.*
                from table t
                order by DateTimeRow desc
               ) t
         ) tt;
```

You need some identifier(s) in the row to match the table to `inserted`.  That is what `pk` stands for.

Comment: Yes, I have an auto incrementing ID column defined as the primary key. Thanks for the input, I'll play around with it and try implementing it in a trigger when I have it working.